# How to store and echo multiple lines elegantly in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to capture a block of text into a variable, with newlines maintained, then echo it.

However, the newlines don't seemed to be maintained when I am either capturing the text or displaying it.

Any ideas regarding how I can accomplish this?

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

read -d '' my_var <<"BLOCK"
this
is
a
test
BLOCK

echo $my_var
```

**Output:**

> this is a test

**Desired output:**

> this
>
> is
>
> a
>
> test

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add `"` quotes around your variable.

```
echo "$my_var"
```

Comment: Would still like to see related documentation if any1 has it? Thanks for the answer nonetheless

Comment: @SamStoelinga: from 'info echo': 
[`echo' writes each given STRING to standard output, with a space
between each and a newline after the last one.]

Without quotes, echo interprets the lines in the input as separate strings, and prints them out, separated by spaces. With quotes, echo prints the input as one string (which contains many lines).