# How to echo a multi line variable in Github Actions?

Tags: variables, github-actions

I have stored a multiline environnement variable thanks to [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings).

```
- name: copy
  run: |
     echo 'CONTENT_ENV<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
     cat README.md >> $GITHUB_ENV
     echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I would like to get it, but this code give one line :

```
 - name: paste
   run: echo $CONTENT_ENV > index.md
```

The worflow shows the variable properly stored in env (with spaces) :

[image: workflow]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store and echo multiple lines elegantly in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752654/how-to-store-and-echo-multiple-lines-elegantly-in-bash)

Comment: This answer helped me. I think it can be helpfull for you too.
[How to mask a multi-line value in GitHub actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77096723/10859681)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable is properly stored, but you need to add quotes if you want to preserve the newlines :

```yaml
- name: paste
  run: echo "$CONTENT_ENV" > index.md
- name: test
  run: cat index.md
```

Short explanation is that default field separator is [whitespace (space, tab and newline)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120578/146783), so if you don't use quotes, `echo` will consider all newlines separated strings as different arguments. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101842/2614364) for more in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use an option like this

```
- name: Output file
  id: read-file
  run: |
    FILE_CONTENT="$(<${FILE_NAME})"
    printf "npmrc_content<<EOF\n%s\nEOF" "${FILE_CONTENT}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```