# How to mask a multi-line value in GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

Action:

```yaml
- id: sets-a-secret
  run: |
    local_secret=$(doppler secrets get GAR_JSON_KEY --plain)
    echo "::add-mask::$local_secret"
    echo "::set-output name=my-secret::$local_secret"
  env:
    DOPPLER_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DOPPLER_TOKEN }}
```

`local_secret` is equal to:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "contrawork"
}
```

In GitHub log only the first line of the value is hidden:

```
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /var/actions-runner/_runners/1/_work/_temp/10dcce73-cb22-43d9-853d-6c9674f6895e.sh
::add-mask::***
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "contrawork"
}
::set-output name=my-secret::***
##[debug]steps['sets-a-secret']['outputs']['my-secret']='***'
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "contrawork"
}
##[debug]Finishing: Run local_secret=$(doppler secrets get GAR_JSON_KEY --plain)
```

What's the correct way to use `add-mask` to avoid exposing a multi-line value in the output?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by masking each line.

Here's an example:

```
name: Multiline variables

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        
      - name: Set multiline env variable
        run: |
          echo 'MULTI<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo -e "Test\nstring" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Mask multiline env
        run: |
         while read -r line;
         do
           echo "::add-mask::${line}"
         done <<< "${{ env.MULTI }}"
        
      - name: Print multiline secret
        run: echo -e "${{ env.MULTI }}"
```

Comment: but your MULTI will be available in log for "mask..." job

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to masking each line is to emulate what the [actions/toolkit](https://github.com/actions/toolkit) [`setSecret`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/fe3e7ce9a7f995d29d1fcfd226a32bca407f9dc8/packages/core/src/core.ts#L99) command [does](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/fe3e7ce9a7f995d29d1fcfd226a32bca407f9dc8/packages/core/src/command.ts#L80).

The same can be done with this perl command (make sure your environment has perl installed):

```bash
perl -pe 's/%/%25/g;s/\n/%0A/g;s/\r/%0D/g'
```

It's essentially doing a subset of [url-encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) on the input.

Example:

```
- id: sets-a-secret
  run: |
    local_secret=$(doppler secrets get GAR_JSON_KEY --plain)
    echo "::add-mask::$local_secret" | perl -pe 's/%/%25/g;s/\n/%0A/g;s/\r/%0D/g'

    delim="$(head -c7 /dev/urandom | base64)"
    echo "my-secret<<$delim\n$local_secret\n$delim"
  env:
    DOPPLER_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DOPPLER_TOKEN }}
```

Now your outputs should be properly masked.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to do this in a single line with `sed`:

```
echo $local_secret | sed 's/^ */::add-mask::/'
```

Explanation:

`sed` reads the content of `$local_secret` and applies the sed command `s/^ */::add-mask::/` to each line.

- `s/`: denotes a substitute command
- `/^ */`: matches the beginning of the line (`^`), succeeded by a zero-to-many sequence of whitespaces
- `/::add-mask::/`: specifies the string the matched sequence of characters shall be replaced with

I.e., it simply adds the `::add-mask::` statement to the beginning of each line before echoing it, which in consequence will mask it.

Removing the whitespaces at the beginning of a line of the masked line is to also mask the secret, if it should not be preceeded by the whitespaces at some point. For example, this could easily happen in a for-loop.

GitHub’s masking mechanism seems to take care of this already, however I’d still pick this solution in case they change the behavior.